# resthub hibernate mysql id generated error

Tags: mysql, hibernate, resthub

I'm trying to use `Mysql` database instead of `H2` for a simple resthub project, but I get a runtime error.

I get next error, when it tries create table:

```
[INFO] [SchemaExport.java:226] Running hbm2ddl schema export
[INFO] [SchemaExport.java:251] exporting generated schema to database
[ERROR] [SchemaExport.java:348] Unsuccessful: create table SampleResource (id bigint generated by default as identity, name varchar(255), primary key (id))
```

As I understand i need to somehow set annotation to id field. But the problem is that this field is already set in class that i'm extending (**Resource.class**).

PS: is

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
```

correct way to set it for mysql?

Answer (score 0):

I think MySql does not support IDENTITY type generator. Try using ***native***. It will select what is appropriate to MySql.

Thanks.

Comment: The JPA specification says "Note that `SEQUENCE` and `IDENTITY` are not portable across all databases." `native` is not a value that the JPA allows. Did you mean `TABLE` or `AUTO`?